# Как обновить массив который выводиться через ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

```html
<div ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <li ng-repeat="value in arrayx">
    Text: <span style="color: red;">{{value.text}}</span>
    <input ng-model="value.editStatus" type="checkbox">
    <div ng-show="value.editStatus">
      <form ng-submit="updateText()">
        <input type="text" value="{{value.text}}">
        <input type="submit" value="edit">
      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- <h4 ng-show="value.name == 'n2xwewr'">n2xwewr!</h4> -->
  </li>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<script>
function testCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.arrayx = [{
    name: 'name1',
    text: 't1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit wqewq',
    editStatus: false,
  }, {
    name: 'name2',
    text: 't2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amccsaet',
    editStatus: false,
  }, {
    name: 'name3',
    text: 't3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amexzzzzzzt',
    editStatus: false,
  }, {
    name: 'name4',
    text: 't4 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amecccq23t',
    editStatus: false,
  }];


  $scope.updateText = function() {
    // как обновить $scope.arrayx[0].text значением взятого с inputа?
  };
}

</script>
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: достаточно использовать `ng-model`

Answer (score 1):

```
<form ng-submit="updateText(value)">
        <input type="text" ng-model="value.text" value="{{value.text}}">
        <input type="submit" value="edit">
</form>
```

При submit формы, можно уже отправлять данные на сервер и.т.д

Comment: А мне не нужно сохранять данные на сервер. Я просто хочу обновить массив arrayx и сразу же сделать reRender

Comment: В ангуляре двухсторонний дата-байндинг, вы просто меняете данные в инпуте как у меня в примере и они сразу же обновляются в массиве. Если вы хотите менять их только прессов нажатия кнопки, тогда введите еще одну промежуточную модель, в которой будет сохранятся введение значение.  
$scope.updateText = function (value) {
    value.text = $scope.model;
}

Answer (score 0):

Запустить этот код перерисовки страницы

```
$scope.$apply ( function (results) {
            $scope.resers = results;
});
```